# How to validate graqhql input type field?

Tags: express-graphql

I have the following input object type that I want to validate its field by set required.
e.g: I want to set name and phone1 property as required.
I would like to know is there is any way that we can do it. I have searched on the internet so far there is no answer. I am really appreciated for anyone kind help.

```
const input = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: "UserCustomerAddressInput",
  fields: () => {
        id: { type: GraphQLInt },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        homeNumber: { type: GraphQLString },
        phone1: { type: GraphQLString },
        phone2: { type: GraphQLString },
        location: { type: GraphQLString },
        isPrimary: { type: GraphQLBoolean }
  },
});
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "validate its field by set required and so on".

Comment: @DanielReardenm Hello brother e.g: I want to set name and phone1 property as required. How can I achieve that?